# Should I ask and self-answer a basic question about pasting a line multiple times?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm a long time vim user, but I just learned recently that I can paste the yanked lines several times. I think most new users wouldn't know this.

Is it okay if I ask about this, and answer myself?

Comment: What is the actual question you are proposing? "Can I paste a yanked line more than once?"

Comment: (See also the [topic about self-answering](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/163/ask-and-answering-your-own-question) for general self-answering guidelines.)

Comment: @JoshPetrie Yeah, something like that. "How can I paste a yanked line more than once?"

Comment: That seems exceedingly trivial to me, especially without surrounding context for an actual problem. It's also [covered already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700989/paste-multiple-times-in-vim) on StackOverflow rather well and I don't really see it bringing a whole lot of value (that is, a better answer) by reposting it here. This is just my opinion though, you can always *try it and see* what the actual community response is. That's why we're having this beta after all.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I understand. I was just trying to understand what kind of users we're expecting. If everybody on the site would already know this, or can easily find the answer, is it worth asking? My real concern is this actually.

Comment: Probably most people on the site *right now* know the answer, but that's not really the metric you should use to decide to ask the question. Also, I think I changed my mind somewhat; thinking about it, I *do* think it's possible to provide a better and more educational answer than the existing SO ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask the question and see what the actual community response is. It's possible it would get downvoted because people think it's too trivial or too much of an "artificial question," but it's also possible it wouldn't.

This site is in beta for a reason, and a big part of that reason is to help shape it, and as members of the private beta we can generally be considered to be among the more "invested" in the topic. As such you *should not be afraid* to take charge of the direction of the community. That's why you're here.

Be bold.

Comment: I will just ask and not answer myself. Let's see what will happen.

Comment: I don't think it would get a good reaction. So I deleted it. :)

Comment: That's a shame, as I was in the middle of writing an answer. Why are you afraid of a "bad reaction?" Having one helps document how the site will work. Having no question at all just creates a zero-sum situation.

Comment: I was just trying to ask it like a beginner. Like someone who doesn't know when you delete a line, yank buffer changes.

Comment: But I'm afraid it would cost me a lot of rep.

Comment: That's sort of not a very good reason, in my opinion. It's just a pointless number on a site that might not even get out of beta, and the amount of reputation you could possible lose from the question is generally going to be outweighed by any other positive participation you have in the future.

Comment: Okay, I'll undelete it. Oh my...

Comment: Oops, my post has gone. I'll have to rewrite it.

Comment: Here's the question. What do you think? http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/710/can-i-paste-a-yanked-line-even-if-i-delete-a-line

Comment: I think this question is okay, because it's a duplicate of a well answered question. So, I have my answer.